# Can't re-index new products after upgrading to version 1.6

Tags: php, magento

I've upgraded my site from version 1.4.0.1 to version 1.6.
I've deleted all the products from the website and did "reindex all" that was finished successfully.
When I try to create a new product and than do a re-index again I get this error :

```
Product Attributes index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`.../catalog_product_index_eav`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_IDX_EAV_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CAS)' in .../lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
```

I've tried to `TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_product_index_eav` but it didn't help.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you're doing and major upgrade and removing all products it might be simpler to start anew and import the customers.

Comment: I have a lot of costume attributes and CMS content that will take A long time to copy. Sadly it doesn't look like magento offers an export and import of this information.

Answer (score 17):

This only removes rogue data that shouldn't be there.

I've expanded the above as it may save some hours of digging:

```
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_datetime` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_gallery` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_group_price` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
#originals with formatting fixed:
delete from `catalog_category_product` WHERE product_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete from `catalog_category_product` WHERE category_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_category_entity); 
delete from `catalog_product_website` WHERE product_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity); 
delete from `catalog_product_index_eav_idx` WHERE entity_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity); 
delete from `catalog_product_index_eav` WHERE entity_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity); 
delete from `catalog_product_link` WHERE product_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity); 
delete from `catalog_product_relation` WHERE parent_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
```

Comment: I've found this also helps for  FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT_1_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID constraint error  `DELETE pf1.*
FROM catalog_product_flat_1 pf1
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity p ON pf1.entity_id = p.entity_id
WHERE ISNULL( p.entity_id ) `

Comment: This is what i was looking for for a long time. Thanks Man!

Answer (score 1):

I used following queries to clean catalog tables;

```
delete from `catalog_category_product` WHERE product_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity)

delete from `catalog_category_product` WHERE category_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_category_entity) 

delete from ` catalog_product_website` WHERE product_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity) 

delete from ` catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` WHERE entity_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity) 

delete from ` catalog_product_index_eav_idx` WHERE entity_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity) 

delete from ` catalog_product_index_eav` WHERE entity_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity) 

delete from ` catalog_product_link` WHERE product_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity) 

delete from ` catalog_product_relation` WHERE parent_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity)
```

After this i was able to reindex from admin panel.

Comment: What the sql queries are saying is 'remove text or remove numbers where the product no longer exists in the main product table' so yes it's removing data but its removing data that would cause constraint problems when indexing anyway. Its sort of like having arms and legs floating around without any body. Lets get rid of those things.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this on a live site, you probably need to do the reindex process from the command line with Apache turned off.

http://overlycaffeinated.com/2011/02/when-reindexing-in-magento-fails-use-the-command-line/

This explains how to do this.

Comment: I'm doing the reindex process from the command line on a development environment with only one test product (that I created after I deleted all the products). The indexing works fine when there are no products