# Magento 1.8 reindex all

Tags: php, magento, pdo

Since a few weeks our reindex will not work anymore and crash with the following error:

```
Product Attributes index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hcomputers_mag`.`catalog_product_index_eav`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_IDX_EAV_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE)' in /var/www/hcomputers/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/hcomputers/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/hcomputers/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/hcomputers/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/hcomputers/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /var/www/hcomputers/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /var/www/hcomputers/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#6 /var/www/hcomputers/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#7 /var/www/hcomputers/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php(48): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromSelect(Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'catalog_product...', Array, false)
#8 /var/www/hcomputers/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(153): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4->insertData(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav_Source), Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'catalog_product...', Array, false)
#9 /var/www/hcomputers/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(113): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromTable('catalog_product...', 'catalog_product...', false)
#10 /var/www/hcomputers/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav/Abstract.php(54): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->syncData()
#11 /var/www/hcomputers/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav.php(185): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav_Abstract->reindexAll()
#12 /var/www/hcomputers/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav->reindexAll()
#13 /var/www/hcomputers/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#14 /var/www/hcomputers/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#15 /var/www/hcomputers/shell/indexer.php(166): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#16 /var/www/hcomputers/shell/indexer.php(212): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#17 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hcomputers_mag`.`catalog_product_index_eav`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_IDX_EAV_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE)' in /var/www/hcomputers/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/hcomputers/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/hcomputers/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/hcomputers/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/hcomputers/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /var/www/hcomputers/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /var/www/hcomputers/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#6 /var/www/hcomputers/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php(48): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromSelect(Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'catalog_product...', Array, false)
#7 /var/www/hcomputers/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(153): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4->insertData(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav_Source), Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'catalog_product...', Array, false)
#8 /var/www/hcomputers/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(113): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromTable('catalog_product...', 'catalog_product...', false)
#9 /var/www/hcomputers/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav/Abstract.php(54): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->syncData()
#10 /var/www/hcomputers/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav.php(185): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav_Abstract->reindexAll()
#11 /var/www/hcomputers/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav->reindexAll()
#12 /var/www/hcomputers/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#13 /var/www/hcomputers/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#14 /var/www/hcomputers/shell/indexer.php(166): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#15 /var/www/hcomputers/shell/indexer.php(212): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
```

Things I've tried:

- Truncate all the catalog_category_flat_store_# (1 - 40) tables
- Truncate all the catalog_product_flat_# (1 - 40) tables
- Tried, as suggested somewhere else to delete the constraints.
- Ran the Reindexer while apache was turned off.

The weird thing is, that the "Product Prices" index's status is still Processing while there is no indexer running. When I try to remove the lock files in var/locks they are immediately generated again like there is still something trying to index, which isn't.

Any help'd be appreciated, since we're running a blank here!

Comment: FYI, Magento now has its [own StackExchange site](http://magento.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks, asked it there as well.

Answer (score 12):

The `catalog_product_index_eav` table has a foreign key constraint named

```
FK_CAT_PRD_IDX_EAV_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID
```

Looking at this table's definition

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav` (
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  `attribute_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Attribute ID',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Store ID',
  `value` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Value',
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`value`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_EAV_ENTITY_ID` (`entity_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ID` (`attribute_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_EAV_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_EAV_VALUE` (`value`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_EAV_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_IDX_EAV_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_IDX_EAV_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Product EAV Index Table';
```

we can see the foreign key definition is

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_IDX_EAV_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` 
FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) 
REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

This means for every `entity_id` row in `catalog_product_index_eav`, there needs to be an identical, corresponding `entity_id` value in `catalog_product_entity`.

The root of your problem is for some reason (either a rouge extension, errors caused by randomly typing in SQL from the internet, or performing data updates with disabled indexes), Magento's indexing attempts to update data in `catalog_product_index_eav` that violates this rule.  The next step is identifying what Magento's doing so you can fix the data.

If we look at your call stack, this looks like a good place to start debugging

```
#10 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav/Abstract.php(54): 
Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->syncData()
```

Jumping to that source file, we see the following bit of code

```
public function syncData()
{
    $this->beginTransaction();
    try {
        /**
         * Can't use truncate because of transaction
         */
        $this->_getWriteAdapter()->delete($this->getMainTable());
        $this->insertFromTable($this->getIdxTable(), $this->getMainTable(), false);
        $this->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->rollBack();
        throw $e;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

As part of its indexing process, Magento tries to sync data from an "index table" (`getIdxTable`), to a "source" (`getMainTable`) table.

```
public function insertFromTable($sourceTable, $destTable, $readToIndex = true)
{
    //...
}
```

For this particular index, the index table is `catalog_product_index_eav_idx`, and the source table is `catalog_product_index_eav`.

**Note**: Be careful with your terminology around here, things are confusingly named.  The "Source" table is the table we're copying to.  (I believe it's called the source table because it's the "source" a normal Magento system will query from when it needs information)

So, Magento is trying to sync a row from `catalog_product_index_eav_idx` to the table `catalog_product_index_eav`.  However, this causes the previously mentioned foreign key error.  This leads us to two possible conclusions

1. The `catalog_product_index_eav_idx` has `entity_id` rows that do not exist in `catalog_product_entity`.
2. The `catalog_product_index_eav` table has (through previous manipulation with index checks turned off) `entity_id` rows that do not exist in `catalog_product_entity`.

So, your mission here is to figure out which entity_id rows in `catalog_product_index_eav` and `catalog_product_index_eav_idx` don't exist in `catalog_product_entity`, and manually delete said rows (from `catalog_product_index_eav` and `catalog_product_index_eav_idx`).

If it were me, and my `catalog_product_entity` table wasn't too large, I'd start with the following queries (these are untested, as I don't have any Magento tables with the above invalid data states)

```
SELECT * 
FROM catalog_product_index_eav_idx 
WHERE NOT (entity_id IN (SELECT entity_id from catalog_product_entity));

SELECT * FROM catalog_product_index_eav 
WHERE NOT (entity_id IN (SELECT entity_id from catalog_product_entity));
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I appreciate the work you did. Unfortunately all entity_id rows in both the catalog_product_index_eav and catalog_product_index_eav_idx tables are present in catalog_product_entity.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Its a fantastic walkthrough on how to debug and fix indexing messages. I see 1000s of posts on the web of people freaking out not knowing how to fix Magento indexing issues and if they followed this guide they could get closer to the cause of the problem.

Comment: BTW, running this query fixed the problem for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19837851/2109405

Comment: `catalog_product_index_eav_idx` table had no foreign keys in my 1.7 installation. I don't know if that happened due to our mistake or Magento's. It contained a million orphan rows because of that. So I truncated it and added foreign keys for `entity_id`, `attribute_id` and `store_id` and set them all to `CASCADE`. Then I reindexed `catalog_product_attribute`. The table is still empty. I suppose it will reindex when I next to `reindexall`. Anyway, that may fix some things.

Comment: will explained and finally i got the issue in my case. In my case the issue was because of child product attributes are indexing against parent products and hence those attributes was appearing in layered navigation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to answer my own question. http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/265847/

The reply from Olivned helped me out.

Thanks for your help!